# Table won't center even though i use the center environment

Tags: tables

I am trying this:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Tabel over interesseparter}
\label{table:1}

 \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||}

 \hline
 Interesseparter & Aktører & Teknologibærere & \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 Beboere & Kommunen & Producenter & \\ 
 \hline
 Boligforeninger & Forsikringsselskaber & Udvikler & \\
 \hline
 Miljøorganisationer & Politikere & Ingeniører/Arkitekter & \\
 \hline
  & Finansielle instutioner & & \\ 
 [1ex] 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

but for some reason the table itself won't center; however, the table caption is centered.

Comment: Please provide us a executable minimum working example (MWE).

Comment: The entries in the table cells are already centered. Actually, it's not reflecting because of long sized content.

Comment: Never include float environment (`figure`, `table`, ...) in any other environment! For centering table on page use `\centering` command after `\begin{table}`.

Comment: Also you define table with four columns, but use only three.

Comment: I want the table itself centeret, How do i do that?

@Zarko perfekt, that worked! thanks!

Comment: @MortenMandsberg, see examples in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

- Never include float environment (figure, table, ...) in any other environment! - For centering table on page use \centering command after \begin{table}.
- you define table with four columns, but use only three

After correcting your code fragmen (and adding one suggestion of different table design), i obtain the following result:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout, about it you not provide any information)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}   % used in the second example
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Tabel over interesseparter}
\label{table:1}
    \centering
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c||}
 \hline
 Interesseparter & Aktører & Teknologibærere \\ [0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
 Beboere & Kommunen & Producenter  \\
 \hline
 Boligforeninger & Forsikringsselskaber & Udvikler  \\
 \hline
 Miljøorganisationer & Politikere & Ingeniører/Arkitekter \\
 \hline
  & Finansielle instutioner & \\
 [1ex]
 \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
Personally I prefer the following table design:
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Tabel over interesseparter}
\label{table:1}
    \centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
 \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
 Interesseparter        & Aktører               & Teknologibærere   \\ 
    \midrule
 Beboere                & Kommunen              & Producenter       \\
 Boligforeninger        & Forsikringsselskaber  & Udvikler          \\
 Miljøorganisationer    & Politikere            & Ingeniører/Arkitekter \\
                        & Finansielle instutioner   &               \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```